# How do I keep a postgres table up to date using instagrams api?

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a table in postgres with the response I get from the instagram api.

I saved the response as a json file and imported it using navicat but when I saved the import job in navicat it ends up as a nppi file. In the nppi file I can change the source to the http address but I cant use that import file in pgadmin.

How do I make this automatic? I could do it if the import file was in sql but it's as not. Am I missing something that could be easier? In pgAdmin the import wizard doesn't have json as an option. I'm still using navicat's free trial so I don't want to be stuck with it because of this.

Is there an easy way to get a postgres table to update with the instagram api?

Comment: You will have to write a script, I'm afraid.